# I need assistance to Sanitise output string database based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I decided to write a post on forum to ask maybe someone have had similar task or have proficiency with SQL to help me out with the report I need to provide.

What I need to do pull the data to get all categories without subcategories from database. Unfortunately, there is discrepancy in database because some records have different format and some of them contain different odd characters as well as nulls.

I managed to remove ones containing end tag '>' but I am struggling with removing other characters. 
Below is my current query with current output and expected result.

Please can someone have a look and help if it possible.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(Category, 1 ,
        CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX('>', Category) = 0 THEN LEN(Category)
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Category) = -1 THEN LEN(Category)
           ELSE CHARINDEX('>', Category) -1 
        END) AS 'Category',
    COUNT(Category) AS 'No. Listings'
FROM
    tbl_Listing
GROUP BY
    SUBSTRING(Category, 1 ,
        CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX('>', Category) = 0 THEN LEN(Category)
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Category) = -1 THEN LEN(Category)
           ELSE CHARINDEX('>', Category) -1 
        END) AS 'Category',
```

Currently

```
ID ¦ Category                   ¦
---+----------------------------- 
1  | eating,places-to-go
2  | education,clubs,
3  | education,library.
4  | education,parties.
5  | local-service/,    
6  | places-to-go,service,
7  | Null
```

Expected result

```
ID ¦ Category                   ¦
---+----------------------------- 
1  | eating
2  | education
3  | education
4  | education
5  | local-service
6  | places,
7  | Null
```

Comment: Do you really want `"places,"` with a trailing comma?

Comment: This is exactly I was looking for. You save me a lot of time Marc_S. I have have now what I needed to complete the report. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `charindex()`, use `patindex()`:

```
select left(category, patindex('%[,/>]%', category + ',') - 1) as CleanString
```

This makes it much easier to add additional "odd" characters.

Comment: Yup.  Even better

Answer (score 2):

Notice in the CHARINDEX() we replace the `slash` with a `comma` and add a `comma` as a fail-safe

Not clear why the last places-to-go is just places

**Example**

```
Select *
      ,CleanString = left([Category],charindex(',',replace([Category],'/',',')+',')-1)
 From  YourTable
```

Returns

```
ID  Category                CleanString
1   eating,places-to-go     eating
2   education,clubs,        education
3   education,library.      education
4   education,parties.      education
5   local-service/,         local-service
6   places-to-go,service,   places-to-go
7   NULL                    NULL
```